# Synfony demo: no route found for "GET /_configurator/" & ResourceNotFoundException

Tags: php, apache, symfony, demo

I wanted to learn Symfony and decided to get the demo app, they've released.

I have an Ubuntu 14.04 server running apache 2.4.7 that seems to apply for all Symfony requirements.

However on a fresh install of the demo, already on the first step, I'm unable to configure it by going to the web/config.php as the "Configure your Symfony Application online" link throws me an error with 2 exceptions:

Error:

> No route found for "GET /_configurator/" (from http://example.com/symfony/symfony_demo/web/config.php")

And 2 exceptions:

> 404 Not Found - NotFoundHttpException
>
> 1 linked Exception: ResourceNotFoundException

In the log I have this:

> ERROR - Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: "No route found for "GET /_configurator/" (from "http://example.com/symfony/symfony_demo/web/config.php")" at /var/www/example/public_html/symfony/symfony_demo/app/cache/dev/classes.php line 2056

I've tried googling for the issue and searched on the Stackoverflow, but so far have had no luck figuring out what it could be or what could be wrong.
As I'm very new to the Symfony framework and don't yet know how these routes and things work, am hoping someone here can help me.

As I Understood, the config was the place I'm supposed to get everything started including database configuration, I'm completely lost.

Also as a note, I did the installation by first downloading and installing symfony installer:

```
$ sudo curl -LsS http://symfony.com/installer -o /usr/local/bin/symfony
$ sudo chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/symfony
```

and then installing the demo as instructed:

```
$ symfony demo
```

however as I did it on a remote live virtual server I have, I did not run the php server starting command as the whole thing is temporarily in a domains web directory configured in apache.

Thank you very much for any help!

Alari

Comment: Do you have specific config `_configurator` in your `app/config/routing_dev.yml`?

Comment: Scoolnico: no, none, everything is as it was "out of the box" from "symfony demo" install command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Symfony.

The web directory of the installation has three .php files.

1) app.php: this is for production environment (end user)

2) app_dev.php this is for development environment (you)

3) config.php for configuration

number 2 and 3 are only accessible from the localhost out of the box. But if you open the files in your editor then you will quickly find an array that you can extend with an extra ip number. If you add your own ip-number and replace the files on your remote server then you will be able to access them from that ip.

The config.php is not really necessary. You could make the **app/config/parameters.yml** file also manually without config.php. Documentation: http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/configuration.html

Please use a editor that supports yaml files like [netbeans](https://netbeans.org/).

Good luck :-)

Comment: Hi Frankbeen,
Thank you for your answer.
I've already added my IP address to both the web/config.php & web/app_dev.php arrays, as otherwise I couldn't even see the first configuration page :) (But that's the only change)
If I do the config manually from editing the files, will Symfony still install the demo database tables (if it does that in the first place)?

Comment: My biggest concern is right now, that if I want to learn of the demo content, I want it working properly as intended for maximum beneficence and to understand how the system is intended to operate and function :)

Comment: i will take a look to the demo for you. There are some helpfull tutorials on youtube also. i created one myself but i speak dutch on that tutorial :-)

Comment: The demo uses sqlite which doesn't need a mysql server or additional settings. So it is unsure where the errors came from.

Comment: Thank you for all your help and effort! I appreciate it. I did actually follow some tutorial which is where I figured out that the config should display a server setup instead of the errors and logs :)

Comment: Same error comes here also. I think this is because it is the demo version. If you use the standard edition then it works fine. Besides there is no need to change configuration for the demo.

Comment: Do you happen to know what changes have to be made in order to achieve the demo functionality? Or what to put in as database information?

Comment: nothing just install the demo. The demo uses mysqlite which just creates some files.

Comment: Thank you for your help!